# Using Expressions in Spring application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can expressions be used as a right-hand-side value in a Spring application.properties file?

For example, something like this:

```
logging.level.com.acme=#{'${MY_RUN_ENV}'=='PROD'?'WARN':'DEBUG'}
```

That, specifically, does *not* work. But, I'm wondering if I can do something similar to what's intended there

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No you can not use SpEL within properties files.

> [Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such
> expressions are not processed from Application property files.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation)

You can however [use placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders) within properties files, eg:

```
app.name=MyApp
app.description=${app.name} is a Spring Boot application
```

For your use case, you should look at the [profile-specific configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles) mechanism.

Which allows you to load different config based on an environment profile.

Comment: for completeness sake and to make this verbose b/c i dod not grok this: you can put this into your properties file: 
`my-prop: #{'${USERNAME}'.toLowerCase()}-local` this will resolve properly when using `@Value("${my-prop}")` **but wont** in connection with `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: This behavior has since changed: "`SpEL` expressions from application property files are not processed at time of parsing these files and populating the environment. However, it is possible to write a `SpEL` expression in `@Value`. If the value of a property from an application property file is a `SpEL` expression, it will be evaluated when consumed through `@Value`."

Comment: Updated doc anchor link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders

Answer (score 4):

No this is not possible, [From spring boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value):

> Feature @ConfigurationProperties
>
> SpEL evaluation No

Instead you can have an `application-default.properties` in production and in it define `loglevel=WARN`.
And in your `application.properties`:

```
loglevel=DEBUG
logging.level.com.acme=${loglevel}
```

The profile-specific properties file(-default by default) should override the properties from `application.properties`, more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

Answer (score 1):

Use profile based properties file.

**In application-dev.properties :
logging.level.com.acme=WARN**

**and in application-prod.properties :
logging.level.com.acme=DEBUG**

FYI when spring boot doesn't find a propertie  in a profile based file  it use the value in the default one . So you can set properties in application.properties and override them in a profile based file when their value changed.