# Split doesn't work with AbstractEnvironment.getProperty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have following property in my application.properties file.

`test.product.release.version=2003.1`

`test.product.release.year=#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[0]`

When I use the property `test.product.release.year` in my spring controller using `@Value` annotation, it's giving me value as 2003, but when I get the value of it through `AbstractEnvironment#getProperty` I am getting value as

`#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[0]`

How can I get the value 2003 by using AbstractEnvironment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Expressions in Spring application.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704466/using-expressions-in-spring-application-properties-file)

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not use SpEL within properties files.

> [Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such
>   expressions are not processed from Application property files.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value)

You can however [use placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties) within properties files, eg:

```
app.name=MyApp
app.description=${app.name} is a Spring Boot application
```

For your use case, you should look at the [profile-specific configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) mechanism.

Which allows you to load different config based on an environment profile.